# Using superdevmode from eclipse when project is split in server/client/shared

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I currently have 3 eclispe projects in my gwt based solution.

Client which only contains the java/gwt client code. It contains no server code at all.

Server which contains all the server code. It contains a bit of gwt code, in order to support gwt-rpc

Shared which contains the classes which are send between the Client and the Server using gwt rpc. Both Client and Server have a dependency on Shared.

This setup worked fine with gwt 2.6 using Dev Mode, but I really need to upgrade to gwt 2.7 and super dev mode.

So I installed the newest version of the gwt plugin. Removed gwt 2.6 from the plugin, and added gwt 2.7 from a local install.

But if right click on the Client project, and choose "Run as Web application (Super Dev mode) I just get the following exception:

```
Running GPE launcher for GWT-2.6.x version.
Runing CodeServer with parameters: [-noprecompile, -port, 9876, -bindAddress, 127.0.0.1, dk.mt3.libris.LibrisEPubCreator]
Super Dev Mode starting up
   workDir: /tmp/gwt-codeserver-4803081089676947573.tmp
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/TreeLogger;Lcom/google/gwt/dev/CompilerContext;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/dev/cfg/ResourceLoader;Z)Lcom/google/gwt/dev/cfg/ModuleDef;
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.loadModule(Recompiler.java:438)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.initWithoutPrecompile(Recompiler.java:190)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.maybePrecompile(Outbox.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.<init>(Outbox.java:61)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.makeOutboxes(CodeServer.java:156)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:118)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.SuperDevListener$1.run(SuperDevListener.java:112)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. The main issue was that the Shared project still referenced gwt 2.6, instead of gwt 2.7 which caused cascade of failures.